# Leave\Dismiss all current matches - Google play games services

Tags: google-play-games

How can I exit all the current matches (leave or dismiss) for a turnbased match. Basically I want all the current matches to be exited if a player exits multiplayer mode.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use [dismissMatch()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMultiplayer#public-methods) to remove the matches all [GoogleApiClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient) objects registered to the user.

Dismissing a match will not change the state of the match for other partcipants but dismissed matches will never be shown to the dismissing player again.

**HTTP request**

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/turnbasedmatches/matchId/dismiss
```

Note that this request requires authorization with the following scope: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games
```

Comment: Thanks for response. But how do I get the match IDs for all the open matches of the player (to use in dismissMatch())?